# docker inside docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to install docker inside a running docker container.

```
docker run -it centos:centos7
```

My base container is using centos, I can login to running container using `docker exec`. But when I try to install docker inside it using `yum install -y docker` it installs.

But somehow I can't start the docker service with `docker -d &`, it gives me error as:

```
INFO[0000] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge 
WARN[0000] Running modprobe bridge nf_nat br_netfilter failed with message: , error: exit status 1 
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error initializing bridge driver: Setup IP forwarding failed: open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: read-only file system
```

Is there a way I can install docker inside docker container or build image already having running docker? I have already seen [these](https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind) examples but none works for me.

The output of `uname -r` on the host machine:

```
[fedora@ ~]$ uname -r
4.2.6-200.fc22.x86_64
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you provide the whole commands you used to start your base- and in-docker container? There might be something wrong with the arguments you pass.

Comment: Hi Michaelbar, sure below is what I have tried:

docker run -it centos:centos7 bash
install docker inside centos:

Comment: Please extend (edit) your question with the commands.

Comment: yum install -y docker ,
docker -d & ,

below is the output:
INFO[0000] Option DefaultNetwork: bridge
WARN[0000] Running modprobe bridge nf_nat br_netfilter failed with message: , error: exit status 1
FATA[0000] Error starting daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error initializing bridge driver: Setup IP forwarding failed: open /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward: read-only file system

Comment: i have tried the same with ubuntu also, same issue :(

Comment: Please append **into you question** the output of `uname -r`.

Comment: added "uname -r" gives: 
$ uname -r
4.2.6-200.fc22.x86_64

Answer (score 11):

**Update**

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/38016704/372019 I want to show another approach.

Instead of mounting the host's `docker` binary, you should copy or install a container specific release of the `docker` binary. Since you're only using it in a client mode, you won't need to install it as a system service. You still need to mount the Docker socket into the container so that you can easily communicate with the host's Docker engine.

Assuming that you got a base image with a working Docker binary (e.g. the [official docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/docker/)), the example now looks like this:

`docker run\
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock\
  docker:1.12 docker info`

---

Without actually answering your question I'd suggest you to read [Using Docker-in-Docker for your CI or testing environment? Think twice](http://jpetazzo.github.io/2015/09/03/do-not-use-docker-in-docker-for-ci/).

It explains why running docker-in-docker should be replaced with a setup where Docker containers run as siblings of the "outer" or "base" container. The article also links to the original https://github.com/jpetazzo/dind project where you can find working examples how to run Docker in Docker - in case you still want to have docker-in-docker.

An example how to enable a container to access the host's Docker daemon look like this:

```
docker run\
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock\
  -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker\
  busybox:latest /usr/bin/docker info
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Mac with Docker toolbox.

The below command **WON’T WORK**

```
docker run\
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock\
  -v /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker\
  busybox:latest /usr/bin/docker info
```

Because `/var/run/docker.sock` will not be on your OSX filesystem

the Docker daemon is running inside the `boot2docker` VM - and that's where the unix socket is.

So you have to run the container from `boot2docker` VM

```
$ docker-machine ssh default
$ docker run\ 
         -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock\ 
         -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker\ 
         busybox:latest /usr/bin/docker info
$ exit
```

This looks like Docker-in-Docker, feels like Docker-in-Docker, but it’s not Docker-in-Docker, when this container will create more containers, those containers will be created in the top-level Docker.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about a my bad platform specific example. Your example is certainly an improvement, but it's still not platform independent. As soon as the host system and the container base image use different architectures, you'll be lost. I'll update my answer with a more flexible approach.

Answer (score 1):

You need the `--privileged` parameter.

> By default, Docker containers are “unprivileged” and cannot, for
>   example, run a Docker daemon inside a Docker container.

[Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration)

Run your base image with the command `docker run --privileged -it centos:centos7 bash`. Then you may install and run another docker container inside that container.

Comment: hey thanks for quick response, I tried with "--privilaged" , when i run docker daemon inside centos7 container , I get below:

any idea

Comment: INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)
WARN[0000] Udev sync is not supported. This will lead to unexpected behavior, data loss and errors. For more information, see https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#daemon-storage-driver-option
ERRO[0000] WARNING: No --storage-opt dm.thinpooldev specified, using loopback; this configuration is strongly discouraged for production use
ERRO[0000] [graphdriver] prior storage driver "devicemapper" failed: exec: "mkfs.ext4": executable file not found in $PATH

Comment: No, you start the **base** docker container with `--privileged`. The inside container is started without the parameter. Please always provide the whole commands you executed.

Comment: sorry for late reply, yes I am doing exactly the same, started base container as :
docker run --privileged -it centos:centos7 bash
[root@67b98a863bc5 /]# yum install -y docker
[root@67b98a863bc5 /]#docker -d & 

after this I get error message as mentioned in my previous comments. any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

I`ve a similar problems in my vms.

I`ve solve the problem with change the storage file system from image to vfs(in daemon.json file)
like the image bellow

[image]

For image works first create a base image, in my case with centos7

```
FROM centos:7
ENV container docker
RUN (cd /lib/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/; for i in *; do [ $i == \
systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service ] || rm -f $i; done); \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /etc/systemd/system/*.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/local-fs.target.wants/*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*udev*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/*initctl*; \
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/basic.target.wants/*;\
rm -f /lib/systemd/system/anaconda.target.wants/*;
VOLUME [ "/sys/fs/cgroup" ]
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

with this image builded (in my case i called local/c7-systemd) create a second image, installing docker and moving daemon.json to inside.

```
FROM local/c7-systemd
RUN yum install -y yum-utils
RUN yum-config-manager  --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
RUN yum install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.28.2/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
RUN ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose
COPY daemon.json /etc/docker/daemon.json
RUN yum install -y nano
RUN systemctl enable docker

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 8161
EXPOSE 6379
EXPOSE 8761
CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]
```

enjoy!